# how to get previous day date using boost?

Tags: c++, date, boost

I have a set of dates represented as strings and whilst it is easy to convert these to date types, I must perform calculations which will require the previous days date. So for example if I have the date 13-09-2013 I will need to derive the date 12-09-2013. Is there a clean way of achieving this? Ideally using boost.

thanks un advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using namespace boost::gregorian;
date d(2013,Sep,13);
d -= days(1);
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5594afbe8085c02)

Answer (score 3):

Just get the current date, subtract one day, and you have yesterday.